# Flutter/Firestore returns type List<Review> is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when retrieving snapshots from Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to retrieve a collection with it's sub-collection using firestore realtime database and displaying the results in ListViewbut instead I got `type List<Review> is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` and I couldn't get around it.

**Question** What should I change in order for this to return the needed results properly?

This is `reviews_service.dart`:

```
class ReviewsService {
  var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<T>> reviewsCollectionStream<T>({
    @required String path,
    @required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data),
  }) {
    final reference = firestoreInstance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) =>
        snapshot.docs.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data())).toList());
}
```

Those are my model classes `review.dart` and `client.dart`

```
class Review {
  final String reviewTitle;
  final String reviewContent;
  final Client owner;

  Review(
    {this.reviewTitle,
    this.reviewContent,
    this.owner});

  factory Review.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return Review(
      reviewTitle: map['revieewTitle'],
      reviewContent: map['reviewContent'],
      owner: Client.fromMap(map['owner']),
    );
  }
}

class Client {
  final String clientUID;
  final String clientEmail;
  final String clientName;

  Client({this.clientUID, this.clientEmail, this.clientName});

  factory Client.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return EndUser(
      clientUID: map['clientId'],
      clientEmail: map['clientEmail'],
      clientDisplayName: map['clientName'],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's where I retrieve the data and display them in the Listview `reviews_page.dart`:

```
class _ReviewsPageState extends State<ReviewsPage> {
  final reviews = _mReviewService.reviewssCollectionStream(path: "reviews", builder: (data) => Review.fromMap(data));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
           stream: reviews,
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    Review rev = new Review(
                        reviewTitle: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewTitle"][index].toString(),
                        reviewContent: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewContent"][index].toString(),                      
                        owner: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewOwner"][index]);
                    return Review(review: rev,);
                  },
               );
              } else {return Center(child: Text('there are no reviews'));}
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** I got working the retrieving is running properly my only problem now is that the `Client` subcollection is null! is there anything wrong with `Stream<List<T>> reviewsCollectionStream<T>({...})` ?

This is what I did:
in `reviews_page.dart` and inside `itemBuilder`:

instead of

```
Review rev = new Review(
                reviewTitle: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewTitle"][index].toString(),
                reviewContent: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewContent"][index].toString(),                      
                owner: (snapshot.data as Map)["reviewOwner"][index]);
```

I recovered it `as List`:

```
//only one line that's all what it takes
Review rev = (snapshot.data as List)[index];
```

*but I still cant retrieve the subcollection of `clients`*

Answer (score 1):

Firestore Snapshots [don't include subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005894/12163274)

> If you want subcollection data, you'll have to make new query using the subcollection name that you know ahead of time

Also, see this [link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) for reference on how to get subcollection data